# Store Custom Kotlin Data Class to disk

Tags: android, kotlin, persistence, data-class

I'm having trouble figuring out a good way to do a Favorites list. I have a recycler view with a button to store an item to `Favorites`, I can easily just store this items `id` but then I have to remake network calls just to get some basic info to fill the list item view.

Here is a screen shot of my recycler view..

[image: RecyclerView]

These items are a simple data class defined as follows

```
data class CoinListItem(
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: String? = null,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String? = null,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("symbol")
    val symbol: String? = null,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("website_slug")
    val slug: String? = null,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("quote")
    val quoteItem: CoinListQuoteItem? = null,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("tags")
    val tags: List<String>? = null): Parcelable
```

Is there a way to save custom objects to disk?

Comment: use a database, for android i recommend Room or Realm

Comment: Have my answer helped you, or have you found some other correct one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep. You can depict class as Serializable `CoinListItem(...): Serializable` thus you tell the system that it can be serialized to and deserialized from text. Next - you create `File` serialize your object by

```
    val item = CoinListItem()
    val file = FileOutputStream("file.txt") // here should be a full path and name
    val outStream = ObjectOutputStream(file)

    // Method for serialization of object
    outStream.writeObject(item)

    outStream.close()
    file.close()
```

To deserialize it use

```
    val file = FileInputStream("file.txt")
    val inStream = ObjectInputStream(file)

    // Method for deserialization of object
    val item = inStream.readObject() as CoinListItem

    inStream.close()
    file.close()
```

Hope it helps.